# Rewrite if not a certain file which is called by AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, .htaccess

I am using a routing library called [Grapnel.js](https://github.com/gregsabia/Grapnel.js/tree/master). It takes urls in the form of `index.php#something/something`, so I'm using htaccess to rewrite `/something/something` to that. But I want to be able to have 2-3 `something`s, so I use the `QSA` flag to add it as a query parameter.

The problem is that the htaccess is applying to the ajax call apparently, and causing an infinite loop. I've tried using

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/file.php
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /#$1 [NE,R,QSA,L]
```

and

```
RewriteRule ^[^file](.+)$ /#$1 [NE,R,QSA,L]
```

The Javascript is:

```
router.get('*', function(req){
    var first = req.params[0];
    var parts = first.split("/");
    var len = parts.length;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'file.php', 
        data: {
            parts: parts,
            len: len
        }
    }).done(function(data) {
        $('#output').html(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: You want to rewrite to `/file.php#something/something` OR `/index.php#something/something` ?

Comment: The `file.php` does processing of the query parameters. The main file is `index.php`.

Comment: Its still not clear what URL you are trying to rewrite. AJAX code is sending request to `file.php`. When and where request is reaching to `index.php`?

Comment: All the code is in `index.php`... A url in the form of `/something/something` should rewrite to `/#something/something` which is equivalent to `/index.php#something/something`. The information grabbed from the url by Grapnel is sent to `file.php` using AJAX. The problem is because of the rewrite rules, it's causing an infinite loop (in the console.)

Comment: Ok so you want all `/file.php` requests to skip being rewritten to `/#foo/bar`?

Comment: Yes, because of the infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /#$1 [NE,R,L]
```